# Inverse Laplace transformation of Bessel and exponential

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, inverse-laplace

I'm trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of
$$\mathrm{e}^{-\beta\alpha}J_0(\frac{\beta\alpha}{2})^2$$ where $\alpha=const$. Would an idea be because since I'm looking for the $\alpha\rightarrow\infty$, to calculate the asymptotic form of $J_0(x)$ i.e., $\sqrt{\pi/x}\cos(x-\pi/4)$ and try it that way?

But I can't seem to solve it that way either...

Comment: I think your idea works, so asymptotic form of it simplify to $$\dfrac{2e^{-\alpha\beta}}{\pi\alpha\beta}\left(1+\sin \alpha\beta\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

I think your idea works, so asymptotic form of it is
$$\dfrac{2e^{-\alpha\beta}}{\pi\alpha\beta}\left(1+\sin \alpha\beta\right)\tag{1}$$
also $\dfrac{1+\sin \alpha\beta}{\alpha\beta}$ is bounded and 
$$\dfrac{e^{-\alpha\beta}}{\alpha\beta}\left(1+\sin \alpha\beta\right)\to0$$
as $\alpha\to\infty$ where $\beta$ is a constant, then $(1)$ has the inverse Laplace transform. With $f(u)=\dfrac{e^{-u}}{u}\left(1+\sin u\right)$, $u=0$ is a simple pole and the residue of 
$$f(u) e^{t u}$$
is $1$, sum od residues is $1$, then the final answer should be $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: Thanks this is great! I was just refreshing myself on residue calculus and (for your $f(u)$) I get the same answer. I've been looking into keeping the $\alpha$ term, and looking at the Laurent series, and $\mathrm{e}^{tu-au}J_0(au/2)^2$ doesn't have any poles. How would one do this?

Comment: I don't know. As you know the final answer is asymptotic, not an exact.

Comment: @LewisProctor If $\beta$ is real, (1) as a function of $\alpha$ is not bounded on a vertical line. In fact, it grows exponentially and the inverse transform doesn't exist as an ordinary function and doesn't exist even as a tempered distribution. Same if $\alpha$ is a real constant and (1) is a function of $\beta$.